# Advantages of using sounds in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm wondering if there are other (if any) possible advantages of using sounds than disabling audio completely.

I just bumped into a Reddit post :

https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/2i0nd1/you_can_hear_the_recall_of_enemies_even_if_you/

And it tells that you can hear the recall of an enemy in a nearby bush, which was true.

Another I can tell is certain champs (like Ezreal and Jinx) are usually saying something when casting [their ult], so you know you can dodge it if you'll listen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to play with sound, however music can sometimes be distracting.

The statement of the reddit post that says you can hear an enemy recalling is correct, also that you hear certain abilities but the most important thing: **You can hear Skillshots hitting enemies in a bush**.

Take Morganas Q for example. The skillshot has no graphical indication on whether an enemy is hit or not (only the range) especially if you hit them at max-range. It does however has a sound indicator. So basically if you have no vision, it's important to have the sound on while checking bushes.

Also a thing to note, you can hear (and sometimes see) enemy spells and ward-placements through the fog of war which helps you locate an enemy you have no vision on.

Overall, try to keep the sound-effects on. If you're a person that can't play with music then just make sure that the music isn't too loud so you can still hear the spells/effects of the game. There are also people who play worse without the ingame music which sounds ridiculous but it's a serious matter of habit.

Comment: I did so because the Audio settings told me that Disabling sound may improve performance (urged 'cause of using low-end laptop). It's kind of unfair esp. to deaf players.

Comment: True it is unfair to deaf players, but how unfair is the game to blind people then? Of course people with handicap won't have 100% of the possibilities offered to a healthy person. That's not a reason to remove it and reduce game design for the vast majority of players.

Comment: It is worth noting that it is completely possible to disable the MUSIC completely but not the normal sound effects.